# Solving system of polynomial equations of order 4 in 8 uknowns with known structure

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a big system of 8 polynomial equations in 8 unknows $\kappa_i$, of which I want to find all solutions programmatically and have no starting guesses.
The equations are of the form:
\begin{equation}
f_0 + \sum_i f_ik_i + \sum_{j\neq i}\sum_i f_{ij}k_ik_j + \sum_{k  \neq j}\sum_{j\neq i}\sum_i f_{ijk}k_ik_jk_k  + \sum_{h \neq k}\sum_{k\neq i }\sum_{j\neq i}\sum_i f_{ijkh}k_hk_ik_jk_k = 0 
\end{equation}
There never appears a power higher than $1$ for a given monomial.
The coefficients are real floats which can be re-arranged to rationals if required.
I have attempted computing a Groebner bases for this set of equations (in sympy) but the calculation did not finish.
Since the power is at most one I am able for a set of special coefficients to reduce the problem to 6 unknows by substitution, but that also doesn't help either.
What options to I have, other than using non-linear algorithm and starting with random guesses?
I expect the system to have a discrete set of solutions.
Could one start with the solutions of the linear system associated with it and build up an ODE in the terms $f_{ij}, ...$ of higher order?

**Edit**

It helps to explain how the equations have been derived and their structure. Those are derived from 4 different systems, each of 4 unknowns with 2 equations. There are 8 commonality constraints in between the 16 unknows which makes some equal and create coupling in between the 4 systems. More in detail, the 4 systems are written in matrix form, $\mathbb{S}_a $ being a $[2\times 16]$ real matrix with all elements different from 0, as:
\begin{equation}
 \underbrace{\left[ \begin{matrix}  \mathbb{S}_a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \mathbb{S}_b & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \mathbb{S}_c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathbb{S}_d    \end{matrix} \right]}_{\mathbb{S}}  \underbrace{ \left[ \begin{matrix}  \mathcal{V}_{\{\mathbf{q}_a\}} \\ \mathcal{V}_{\{\mathbf{q}_b\}} \\ \mathcal{V}_{\{\mathbf{q}_c\}} \\ \mathcal{V}_{\{\mathbf{q}_d\}}  \end{matrix} \right]}_{ \mathcal{V}\{ \mathbf{q} \} } = 0 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{V}_{\{q_a\}}=\left[\begin{matrix}1\\\kappa_1\\\kappa_2\\\kappa_3\\\kappa_4\\\kappa_2 \kappa_4\\\kappa_1 \kappa_2\\\kappa_3 \kappa_4\\\kappa_1 \kappa_3\\\kappa_2 \kappa_3\\\kappa_1 \kappa_4\\\kappa_1 \kappa_2 \kappa_3\\\kappa_1 \kappa_2 \kappa_4\\\kappa_1 \kappa_3 \kappa_4\\\kappa_2 \kappa_3 \kappa_4\\\kappa_1 \kappa_2 \kappa_3 \kappa_4\end{matrix}\right]
\end{equation}
and so on for the other ones up to $\kappa_{16}$. The 8 commonality conditions are:
\begin{equation}
 \kappa_3 = \kappa_{11} \;\;\;\;\; \kappa_4 = \kappa_{12} \;\;\;\;\; \kappa_{7}=\kappa_{15}\;\;\;\;\; \kappa_{8}=\kappa_{16}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \kappa_{1} = \kappa_{5} \;\;\;\;\;  \kappa_{9}=\kappa_{13} \;\;\;\;\ \kappa_{2}=\kappa_{6} \;\;\;\;\; \kappa_{10}=\kappa_{14}
\end{equation}
After some tedious re-arrangement, this leads to 49 monomials and 8 unknows, given by $\mathbf{q}=[\kappa_{1},\kappa_{2},\kappa_{3},\kappa_{4},\kappa_{7}, \kappa_{8}, \kappa_{9}, \kappa_{10}]$

Comment: There are many ways to help with the computation of Groebner bases, e.g., first solving certain subsystems, or special cases, or changing the monomial order, or trying to avoid "the parts with too many solutions". Are there obvious solutions?

Comment: I cannot think of any special solutions, but the equations have a lot of structure. I have tried the three different lexichographic orders implemented in sympy but no success. I have tried a few different orders (there is one that allows to solve two linear equations first), solving for  $\kappa_1$ and then for $\kappa_8$. All other equations become quadratic after those steps. Regarding sub-systems, it may help to better explain how the equations have been derived. They originate from a smaller subset of systems with some constraints.

Comment: I was able to find a solution, though I was lucky :)

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I found that two of the commonality conditions were redundant because of how the matrices   $ \mathbb{S}_i$ are structured, so the system is in fact under-determined. Removing those redundant one, the system can be diagonalized more than I expected in smaller systems with only 2 unknows each if with an appropriate order.
Based on two chosen DOFs ($\kappa_{3}$ and $\kappa_4$ for instance),  I am able to solve with simple quadratic formulas all other 6 variables sequentially, (first $\kappa_{1}$ and $\kappa_{2}$, then all the remaining others as well).

Even if redundancy would have not been the case, one could have followed the same approach and treat the two initial variables as unknowns; would have ended up with a much higher order equation in only those two variables which could have been solved more easily with the Groebner approach.